# Get Type Of a Type

Tags: c#

I know I can get a [`System.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) of an instance of my class by using [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

```
Point pt = new Point(0, 0);
System.Type ptType = pt.GetType();
```

But what can I do when I want get `System.Type` of a type:

```
System.Type pointType = Point.GetType();
```

It does not work, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) expression:

```
System.Type pointType = typeof(Point);
```

The [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method is used to get the runtime type, whereas the `typeof` expression gets the compile-time type.