# How to create array of type[]?

Tags: c#, types

How to initialize the  array of data types in System.Type Datatype

This sample code i am trying

```
Type[] coltypes = {string, string, string, string, string, string };
```

after I found the solution in this link i am able to understand the problem

[Gettype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800200/get-type-of-a-type)

Solution for this :
 Type[] coltypes = {typeof(string),typeof(int),typeof(double),typeof(string)};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`typeof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) to get the [type object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) for a type:

```
Type[] coltypes = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(double) };
```

Note that using the `typeof` expression is interpreted by the compiler and gets the type object at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

Because `string` is not `System.Type` itself. You can use [`typeof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) to generate it's `System.Type`.

You can use;

```
Type[] coltypes = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma for one thing,

```
Type[] coltypes = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) };
```